Bear React_Native Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager
Has Anyone Solved this? Can't find any solution for this problem. Bear React Native when trying to use react navigation bty following the exact documentation always gives the same error.
I have even tried someone working github example even that gives me the same error.
These are the dependencies:
"dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.31.1"
},
I have tried removing node_modules
./gradlew clean
removing Pods
react-naative-screens: "3.20.0"
none of it has worked.
